# Instagram Feed - jQuery Plugin for Instagram to open in new window

Tags: jquery, html, instagram

I had purchase sometime back "[Instagram Feed - jQuery Plugin](https://codecanyon.net/item/instagram-feed-jquery-plugin-for-instagram/13397600)" their latest version allows us either to use their cloud based API for this or once can host the API on once server and use it unlimited time.

It is working for me but i am facing issue with the plugin as i want it to open items on new window rather than Popup as it  default behaviors is popup

```
   <div data-is data-is-api="PATH OF API FILE"          data-is-source='["@XXX"]' data-is-layout='slider' data-is-columns='4'
         data-is-responsive='[{"minWidth":1924,"columns":4,"rows":1,"gutter":0},{"minWidth":1024,"columns":4,"rows":1,"gutter":0}, {"minWidth":768,"columns":3,"rows":1,"gutter":0}, {"minWidth":500,"columns":2,"rows":1,"gutter":0}]'
         data-is-limit='20',  data-is-custom-c-s-s='my-instashow' style="height:auto; background:none;">
    </div>
```

I have not found any document ion on their website for this open which is pretty strange. I would appreciate if anyone can help me to open this post in new window

Comment: The perils of buying a plugin with 6 months support. I'd be very surprised if anyone here is able/willing to help here. We're not technical support for everyones plugin

Comment: I can understand, I was think of getting lucky to see if someone has came across this issue & may have solution... I have knocked support team doors with no luck so far...